# Assets handling in the play store and on device for multiple DPIs

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play

I'm working on a game that will have quite allot of assets, and if we'll build the game for multiple dpis such as androids xdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi, I'm worried that the play store would download assets for all dpis, and even more worried that the app on the device would store all dpis even though it would not need them.

Does anyone know how the play store and the device handles assets for multiple dpis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build different apks for different dpi  see

http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Thanks allot, this is perfect!